# How to retrieve columns' names based on their value

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, excel-formula, spreadsheet

got a question about google spreadsheet/excel:

Let's say I've got a bunch of rows, each one for a different product. 
Each product could have or not some attributes, indicated by the columns. If it has such an attribute, then there will be "1" in that column, otherwise it'll be empty.

What I need is a formula that retrieves, in a single cell and separated by "," the names of all those columns containing for that row the attribute "1".

Here's an image just to make it easier:

[image]

Comment: Have you considered a pivot table?

Comment: Any code that you've tried?

Comment: Are you looking for a formula that works on both apps? I'm asking because there are functions that works in one app that doesn't on the other or that work a bit differently.

Answer (score 0):

There are some number of problems that should be solved in this question.

- how to show a result, if a value is equal to 1;
- how to concatenate these results;
- how to put a comma separator between results;
- how to remove the last comma separator;

In general, the "laziest" way is to start doing the things really manually, checking each value for 1, then uniting the values of the first row and putting a comma between them. This solves points 1,2,3. 
Point 4 is solved by `LEFT(RESULT,LENGTH(RESULT-2))`, which ignores the last comma and its space. The `IFERROR()` is needed, in case that there are no `1` in the range:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(CONCATENATE(
    IF(B2=1,B1&", ",""),
    IF(C2=1,C1&",","")),
 LEN(CONCATENATE(
    IF(B2=1,B1&", ",""),
    IF(C2=1,C1&", ","")))-2)
 ,"")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Vityata, thanks for the very quick answer. Can you confirm me this formula would only work for column B and C? In my case I'm probably going to add many new columns.. How am I supposed to edit this one to work for, let's say, 30 columns?